# Best practices for a team using PGP key?

Tags: pgp

We have a team (a security team) and I am wondering how could we use PGP to sign mails. People come and go of course... can't find anything about this with google.

Clarification: I would like the members to be able to send out emails that can be verified as coming from the team without giving out the single key to every member.

Comment: Tons of data on this residing within the web...http://email.about.com/library/weekly/aa110199a.htm

Comment: @Aaron: problem is not using PGP, but handling common PGP key for team.

Comment: @Olli The question stated..."...I am wondering how could we use PGP to sign mails..." That does not sound like it is any way geared towards how to handle the PGP key.

Comment: @Aaron: well, judging from topic ("Best practices for a team using PGP key") it's more about handling PGP key. Have to wait until chx clarifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people are coming and going, you have to either store PGP keys on some secure system where team members can't use it (as in export it for later use) or you have to regenerate it every time someone leaves.

I couldn't find any system for managing PGP keys without having local copy. For example webmail with PGP integration or PGP signing gateway would do; as long as users can't get keys, and you can manage user accounts for that system (to revoke access for members who are leaving).

If you have some kind of internal development team or some of your team members can write short program for that, adding PGP signing gateway to (authenticated, obviously) MTA is not really big task.

Comment: PGP signing gateway, hm, like djigzo? Sounds promising, thanks!